# How to get the height of the div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have 2 div's, left and right, the content in right div is setted dynamically so as its height, so i haven't specified its height in html, now what i want is the height of the left div should be equal to the right div, how to set the height of the left div as per the height of right div, using jquery, i tried

```
$("#leftDiv").height($("RightDiv").height());
```

this does not seems working, as i haven't specified the height of the right div in html.
is there any other wayout, apart from using tables.

Comment: In `$("RightDiv")`, I assume you mean `$("#rightDiv")`? Did you just make a typo here, or did you copy-paste?

Comment: I don't if know you made a copy-paste error or not, but you're missing the `#`-sign in front of the RightDiv selector. It should be `$("#leftDiv").height($("#RightDiv").height());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

Looks like your selector for `RightDiv` is not right or you forgot to wait while the DOM is loaded.

#### Sample

**Html**

```
<div id="leftDiv" style="border:1px solid red">left div</div>
<div id="RightDiv" style="height:100px; border:1px solid red">right div</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
   $("#leftDiv").height($("#RightDiv").height());
})
```

#### More Information

- **[jSFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/56chL/1/)**
- [jQuery - .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [jQuery - .height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Comment: Ok, it was only too demonstrate. Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/56chL/2/.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#leftDiv").height($("#RightDiv").get(0).scrollHeight);
```

Comment: @PPvG it can be used to, depends on needs.

Comment: the need seems to be to make the `div` equally high; not to make `div1` as high as the *conten* of `div2`...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var firstHeight = $("#RightDiv").height() + 'px';
$("#leftDiv").css("height", firstHeight);
```

Comment: I think .css('height') takes the value that is set in CSS and it doesn't matter what actual height is.

Comment: @Alex is correct. To get the computed height (even if no height was set in CSS), use [`.height()`, `.innerHeight()` or `.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/).

Comment: And adding `'px'` is unnecessary, as `.height()` returns *and* accepts `Number` values: http://api.jquery.com/height/#height2

Comment: Im not using  `.height()` but I am using `.css()` to set the height because I dont want to copy all someone else his answer, and `.css()` works fine aswell ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
 if($("#RightDiv").height() > $("#leftDiv").height()){    
           $("#leftDiv").css("height", $("#RightDiv").height() + "px");
        } else {
           $("#rightDiv").css("height", $("#leftDiv").height() + "px");
       }
}
```